# androidx.fragment:fragment (androidx.fragment:fragment) has reported version 1.0.0 as outdated

Tags: android-fragments

androidx.fragment:fragment (androidx.fragment:fragment) has reported version 1.0.0 as outdated. Consider upgrading to one of the following versions before publishing a new release: 1.1.0+

how to fixed this problem in unity

please anyone help me